# Failed R instances + RODBC

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rodbc

Quick question: I am running multiple R instances parallel in batch mode using an RODBC connection, and randomly one (or more) of my instances is failing. If I go back and run the instances one by one, all of them are successful. There is no error in the log, and I am just trying to deduce where exactly the issue is coming from. My main hypotheses are that I am hitting a memory heap top and the instance is failing, or (more probably) there is some kind of time out happening with the RODCB connection. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: What's the error message? What type of RDBMS are you connecting to?

Comment: How many instances do you need to run before it falls over? 2? 1000?  Can you add some extra logging to see exactly when it falls over?

Comment: There are also limits on open connections, both at the OS level and at the R level.  Could you be hitting those?

Comment: I am not receiving an error message, the instance just stops. This is the main problem for debugging. The database is Oracle. I am only running 7 instances, which may have hit a limit, but I do not think that I am hitting a hard limit because sometimes all of the instances will run, and other times I will only be running 5 instances and one of them will fail.

Comment: To Dirk's point, you have to remember to obdcClose(your_connection) after you're done using it.

Comment: Are you using a POSIXct date field? Try changing your POSIXct data to Date data (even if it's not appropriate to your dataset) and let us know if that seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why no error shows, perhaps you could try `options(error = recover)`

I used to get the following error when using multiple database connections:

```
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing)
```

I avoid this error by issuing the following line to close any open connections before issuing a new query:

```
lapply(dbListConnections(MySQL()), dbDisconnect)
```

I took this code from the [R help list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/100956.html).

---

update: one of my collaborators has created a [suite of functions](https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/blob/master/db/R/utils.R) to facilitate database interactions, including `db.con`, `db.open`, `db.close`, and `db.query` that could be used like:

```
## load functions
source("https://raw.github.com/PecanProject/pecan/master/db/R/utils.R")

## example
params <- list(dbname = "mydb", username = "myname", password = "!#@?$")
con <- db.open(params)
mydata <- db.query("select * from mytable;")
db.close(con)
```